# Floating Action Button not displaying properly in Android Kitkat

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have implemented the Floating action button in my app.its not displaying correctly in Android Kitkat but its working correctly above 5.0. Below I have mentioned the XML code

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"

    app:layout_anchor="@id/imageCoverart"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    style="@style/FabStyle"/>
```

and i'm seeing the output like this

[image]

Comment: Add `app:useCompatPadding="true"` for your floating action button

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: when i add above tag its throwing error  Error:(155) No resource identifier found for attribute 'useCompatPadding' in package

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:fabSize` attributeto set FloatingActionButton size, by default Android has "mini" and "normal" sizes. If you want a custom size you should use `app:fabSize` attribute with one pre-defined constant value. For example

```
<resources>
     <dimen name="design_fab_size_normal ">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

More info: https://materialdoc.com/components/fab/#size